# Stabilizer groups as conjugate groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

Reviewing for a test here. I get what they are saying up until the jump that both are conjugate groups. I don't understand how we'd know that just by knowing they are stabilizer groups of the same orbit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot x=y$.  Now $h\in\operatorname{Stab}(y)\iff h\cdot y=y\iff( g^{-1}hg)\cdot x=x$.

To see this last part, suppose $h\cdot y=y$, then
$$\begin{align}
(g^{-1}hg)\cdot x & =(g^{-1}h)\cdot(g\cdot x)\\
& =(g^{-1}h)\cdot y\\
& =g^{-1}\cdot(h\cdot y)\\
& = g^{-1}\cdot y=x.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I get everything except that very last part where you go from h*y=y to the last part. Why is that?

Comment: I've expanded my answer.